# How to find size of a file located on linux box and display in java webapp

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, document

I have a web app which displays a bunch of links to documents. These documents lie on my linux box.

Now i want to show the size of each file in one coloumn.

The solution iam thinking right now is:

After google search i noticed that

```
du -h /home/user/me/doc.txt gives the size of file.
```

So i am thinking of getting a new web service which takes a doc location, connects to my box and runs the above command and spits the size back.

Only concern is i will have some 1000 results. they will be on different folders. so running the above command on each file will take time.

Is there any way to get my work done efficiently.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use java `File` class to read the sizes of your files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use java to recursively read all the files and exclude those not wanted and get the file size but calling du -h is way faster and less code is needed.

```
        //you will problably need to tune up a bit the du command
        String[] cmd = {
        "/bin/sh", "-c", "du -h /home/user/me/*.txt" };//to get all the txt files size in folder

        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**UPDATE**
I have tested on mp3 files in different directories, it takes less than one second with over 6000 files stored in different folders.

Command used:

```
"/bin/sh", "-c", "du -h -a /media/mp3 | grep .mp3"
```